# Call function which is in window resized event from within window scroll event?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called size and a function that depends on it. As the variable depends on the screen width and needs to change if the width varies, I need to have it within a the window resize event. However I also want to call it from with other events such as a scroll event.

```
$(window).resize(function (){

    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        var size = "large";
    }
    else {
        var size = "small";
    }

    function showRow(param) {
        if (size == "large") {
            $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').each(someFunction);
        }
        else if (size == "small") {
            $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 2).removeClass('hidden').each(someFunction);
        }
    }

});

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
    showRow();
  }
});
```

Comment: How about defining the function outside (and have `size` global (might have to be renamed))? Or simply assign the function to a global variable.

Comment: Why have showRow inside of the resize function at all? The way the function is set up, it's meant to be defined as a global variable. You can just pass the size in it

Comment: showRow could be outside the resize function and in fact I think that would make things a lot easier, however it needs to know the value of the variable "size". This variable needs to be recalculated when the window is resized.

Comment: @FelixKling how can I make size global and also recalculate it when the window is resized?

Comment: `var size; $(window).resize(function (){ if ($(window).width() > 1200) { size = 'large'; }});`. `size` doesn't actually have to be global it just has to be in the scope of all functions where you want to to use it.

Comment: That said, maybe you can just use media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, `showRow` is a global var and calculating of the window size occurs in it, so you can call it inside of resize and for scrolling. This is assuming you wanted to also use `showRow` inside of your resize. If you don't have any other code inside of resize, then you can just delete that altogether in the first example

```
var showRow = function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        var size = "large";
    }
    else {
        var size = "small";
    }

    if (size == "large") {
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').each(someFunction);
    }
    else if (size == "small") {
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 2).removeClass('hidden').each(someFunction);
    }
}

$(window).resize(function (){
    showRow();
    // other code
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
    showRow();
  }
});
```

If you don't want to use `showRow` inside of resize then

```
// initialize windowSize
var windowSize = $(window).width() > 1200 ? "large" : "small";

var showRow = function () {
    if (windowSize == "large") {
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').each(someFunction);
    } else if (windowSize == "small") {
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 2).removeClass('hidden').each(someFunction);
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        windowSize = "large";
    } else {
        windowSize = "small";
    }
    // other code
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
        showRow();
    }
});
```